# how to use apply map in Racket

Tags: racket

im writing a function in racket that consumes a list of lists (where the
type of the elements in the inner list may be any type). The function returns a list
of lists – such that for each inner list lst (in the original list) the following is done
– 1. If lst contains at least one number, then lst is replaced with a list of size
two, containing the minimum and maximum in lst, and 2. Otherwise, lst is
replaced with a null.

take into consideration that i have this function that works fine, this function takes list of any and return a list of numbers that the list contain e.x if i give it '( 1 'f 7 'a ) it return '( 1 7)

```
(: sublist-numbers : (Listof Any) -> (Listof Any))
```

so i start write my function and wanted to use this function above here is my code:

```
(: min&max-lists : (Listof Any) -> (Listof Any))

(define (min&max-lists lst)
(apply append (map (lambda (slst)
                     (if (null? slst)
                         '()
                         ((>= (length (sublist-numbers slst)) 1) '(1))
                         )
              )
            lst)) 
  )
```

but for now i wanted to check if at-least i can iterate over each list in the lists but i get an exception

**Type Checker: type mismatch
expected: (Listof Any)
given: Any in: slst
. Type Checker: Cannot apply expression of type Boolean, since it is not a function type in: ((>= (length (sublist-numbers slst)) 1) (quote (1)))
. Type Checker: Summary: 2 errors encountered in:
slst
((>= (length (sublist-numbers slst)) 1) (quote (1)))**

if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

here is an example to a test to this function:

```
(test (min&max-lists '((any "Benny" 10 OP 8) (any "Benny" OP (23)))) => '((8 10) ()))
```

Comment: The type of your interim `min&max-lists` seems to be `(Listof (Listof Any)) -> (Listof (U Null (List 1)))`, so it's just a map (each sublist in the argument produces a value in the result), and the `if` can be much simpler.

Comment: You will get the same error as the second from `((> 1 0) '(1))`. The syntax of `if`  is `(if condition true-value false-value)`, not `(if condition true-value (other-condition other-true-value))`. I think you're confusing it with `cond`.

Comment: it shows me slst is type Any and it expected (Listof Any) so how can i convert it to (Listof Any) or how can i map correctly to get each list in the "Lists of list" , i know the if statement is not correct 100% but it does the job

Comment: `(>= ...)` produces either `#t` or `#f`: `(#t ...)` and `(#f ...)` are errors. The final example shows a "list of lists" argument producing a corresponding list of values: this is what `map` does.